# cell value changed in a R function was not assigned in the output?

Tags: r, function

I encounter an issue in writing a very simple R function. The purpose of the function is the to change a cell value in a data.frame.

[image]

```
f1=function(rn){
  df[rn,2]="b"
}
```

After typing the code:

> f1(1)
>
> df

The df table still looks the same, without changing the cell(1,2). can anyone explain to me why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that your `df` doesnt exist inside your function.

Comment: this is just a small part of a larger function I am writing. I found this is one of the problems why the function didn't work out. What's the way to fix the issue that df does not exist inside the function?

Comment: You will have to assign the result to a df. Make sure you `return(df)`.

Comment: this worked. Thanks!

Comment: why do you think it is a typographical error? As I beginner of R, I found your comment is offensive. I agree that it is a simple question and simple fix, but that shouldn't invalidate the question itself. First of all, it is just part of a larger function,  I do not want to waste others' time by posting the entire function. Second, I did learn the new knowledge from Roman and mtoto  about Return --isn't this the purpose of this forum?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: I think it is much more than a typographical error, it is a misunderstanding of lexical scoping in R. The title is clear enough that it could be useful to someone else. If you really want to close it, close it as duplicate of questions about variable scoping inside a function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this isn't working is because the scope of the function doesn't include df.  Though you can access df becuase it's in the global environment, it doesn't the function can't effect the global environment (one of the side effects of R trying to be a functional language

A quick hacky fix for this is to use the `<<-` operator which accesses the global environment.  Change your function to be:

`function(i) df[i,2] <<- 'b'`

Edit: (can't comment not enough rep) The comments on the original question give a valid solution, but it is very memory and time inefficient since you are passing data.frames instead of modifying them.

Here are some benchmarks (its minimal I guess, but good practice)
Unit: microseconds

        `expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
 df1 <- f(3) 40.742 42.987 51.85747 43.950 61.9140 148.209  1000
        g(3) 37.213 40.421 49.80885 41.704 64.6405 127.998  1000`

Edit2:

`insertRow=function(rn){ if (T1$TRANS[rn]=="STOP") { T2[2,]<-T1[(rn),] return(T2)} return(0) }`

can instead be

`insertRow <- function(rn){ if (T1$TRANS[rn]=="STOP") { T2[2,]<<-T1[(rn),]}}`

Comment: What are the flaws with strong assignment?  If you don't have repetitive variable names (which is good practice) you should be fine. Unless you are using parallel computing, in which case you're answer is no longer determinable (there is a word for this but it is escaping me at the moment).  In this case though, there is clearly no parallel computing that is going to be done.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. My function looks as (with the Return command):  insertRow=function(rn){
    if (T1$TRANS[rn]=="STOP")  {
      T2[2,]<-T1[(rn),]
      return(T2)}
    return(0)
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Sorry if it is supposed to be straight forward, but i  do not see how to apply the code you suggested?

Comment: That won't work... In the case that the if statement is false, your df in your global environment will turn into 0.

just change `<-` in the assignment to `<<-` and get rid of the return statement.  It should be one line.  You can even get rid of the curly braces since there is only one statement following, but that may make code harder to read.  Especially for beginners

Comment: Check my answer again, I wrote out the full function.